# Want to replace one character at specific position in VB 6.0

Tags: replace, vb6

**wordString --> Word for fill in the blank.
key-->Character is replaced.
I have also have the position of the key in keyPos which is calculated randomly**

I'm making a fill in the blanks game. Here I need to create blanks at random position. I'm using `Replace(wordString, key, "_", , 1)`

But this only replace the first occurrence. If my wordString has repeating letters like **APPLE** it will always replace the first **P**

I want to replace the second **P** also. Like AP_LE.

Comment: use a loop to iterate through the characters and use replace method if specified character is encountered.

Comment: but any way `replace()` will remove all instance of the character as said in MSDN [Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I have edited the question which I think will make you understand my need.

Comment: is that position constant or randomly selected?

Comment: check answer from Viktor Ek,it will help.

Comment: The `1` parameter you are passing tells the Replace function the Count (how many characters) to replace. Change your statement to `Replace(wordString, key, "_")` and I think you will get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got another solution myself.
It has 3 text boxes txtInput, txtOutput, txtKeyPos and a command button command1

Code:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
t1 = Left$(txtInput.Text, Int(txtKeyPos.Text) - 1)
t2 = Right$(txtInput.Text, (Len(txtInput.Text)) - Int(txtKeyPos.Text))
txtOutput.Text = t1 & "_" & t2
End Sub
```

This serves my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

OK this is vb.net and not vb6 but here goes::

You should do a *word* approach instead of a *character* approach:

```
Dim sentence as String = "My apple is red."
Dim wordsInSentence() as String = sentence.Split()

Dim Rnd as new Random
Dim wordToBlank as String = wordsInSentence(Rnd.next(0, wordsInSentence.length))
Dim blankedSentence as String = sentence.Replace(wordToBlank, "___")
```

And `blankedSentence` will contain your `sentence` with a random word blanked.

```
My ___ is red.
```

---

EDIT: To instead blank a random *character* in your string, randomise a character index in your string and (if it's not a space) blank that :

```
Dim sentence as String = "My apple is red."

Dim Rnd as new Random
Dim index As single = Rnd.next(0, sentence.length)
While sentence.Substring(index,1) = " "
    index = Rnd.next(0, sentence.length)
End While

Dim blankedSentence as String = sentence.Remove(index,1).Insert(index, "_")
```

And `blankedSentence` contains your `sentence` with a random non-space letter blanked:

```
My ap_le is red.
```

This isn't a very good approach though as all letters of all words, including punctuation, can be the character that is blanked. Other than that it will get you what you wanted.

VB6 version:

```
Dim sentence as String
Dim index As Integer
Dim intUpperBound As Integer
Dim intLowerBound As Integer

sentence = "My apple is red."
intLowerBound = 1 'assuming the first character of the word
intUpperBound = Len(sentence)

Randomize 'initialize the random number generator
index = Int((intUpperBound - intLowerBound + 1) * Rnd) + intLowerBound
While Mid$(sentence, index, 1) = " "
    index = Int((intUpperBound - intLowerBound + 1) * Rnd) + intLowerBound
Wend

Dim blankedSentence As String
blankedSentence = sentence
Mid(blankedSentence, index, 1) = "_" 'replace the current character at index with the new character
```

Comment: I want to make it for a single word like AP_LE. Is it possible.

Comment: Ok, I added an approach to get what you want now that you are being clearer. Hope it helps!

Comment: If it still won't work, get back to us and we can work it out. If it did work for your purpose, please mark it as answer to let others know.

Comment: The code is not working in VB 6.0
This type of assignment is not working -
'Dim sentence as String = "My apple is red." ' (in a single line).
So I break it in two lines.

Then I got 'Invalid qualifier'  at 'sentence.length'

Comment: It is in vb.net, actually. Found it via the vb.net tag and missed you wanted vb6. My bad but hope it helps in some way or that someone can 'fill in the blanks' and translate it.. ;)

Comment: Its ok. Thanks for your effort @Viktor Ek . First I add the vb.net tag by mistake. Later I edited it.

Comment: I added a vb6 translation of your second method. Feel free to edit, or rollback as you see fit.